# how to generate video thumbnail in node.js and save it as a buffer?

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, buffer, video-thumbnails

I want to get the thumbnails of a video at half of it but I should not save the image in a file but get the buffer. I tested ffmepg
`ffmpeg -ss 146 -i video.mp4 -y -an -t 4 source`
but it does not propose to recover the buffer. Do you know a solution?